# Exim limiting number of emails and cc

Tags: exim

`550 maximum allowed line length is 998 octets, got 1014`

Getting this error in emails bouncing back. Is there a setting in exim to solve this problem?

Tried to google it up but cannot find any solution.

Comment: Bouncing back, as in: the _other_ mailserver bounces the mails, or yours?

Comment: It is mine. I think I have found the problem. I have increased the setting `message_size_limit = ${if > {$max_received_linelength}{1014} {1}{0}}` i exim4.conf.template Is this ok to do?

Comment: Please provide the output of `exim4 -bP message_size_limit`, you shouldn't have to alter any template, but set the `message_size_limit` via conf-file.

Comment: Command returns `message_size_limit = 50M`

Comment: Didn't realize the error was based on the number of recipients and CC...sorry. Check @EsaJokinens answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you got is based on [RFC 2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) / [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) (Internet Message Format):

> 2.1.1.  Line Length Limits
>
> There are two limits that this specification places on the number
> of    characters in a line.  Each line of characters MUST be no more
> than    998 characters, and SHOULD be no more than 78 characters,
> excluding    the CRLF.
>
> The 998 character limit is due to limitations in many
> implementations    that send, receive, or store IMF messages which
> simply cannot handle    more than 998 characters on a line.
>
> 2.2.3.  Long Header Fields
>
> Each header field is logically a single line of characters
> comprising    the field name, the colon, and the field body.  For
> convenience    however, and to deal with the 998/78 character
> limitations per line,    the field body portion of a header field can
> be split into a    multiple-line representation; this is called
> "folding".  The general    rule is that wherever this specification
> allows for folding white    space (not simply WSP characters), a CRLF
> may be inserted before any    WSP.

As every decent email client probably conforms to this standard you probably won't reject anything but SPAM if you don't even consider this as a problem and try to solve it.

If you have a long list of addresses in `CC:` field, your email client should add line breaks before the 988 character line length limit. As the [mean email address length](http://www.raycon.com.au/articles.php?n=k9htyces) is 23 characters, that would be approximately 43 addresses per line. If you need to send an email to this many recipients, please consider using `BCC:` field (or a mailing list software with opt-out possibility) instead.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently exim has set this limit. [This](https://blog.dhampir.no/content/exim4-line-length-in-debian-stretch-mail-delivery-failed-returning-message-to-sender) link describes how to modify the

`exim4.conf.template` in order to avoid messages being rejected.

It's just the case to add `IGNORE_SMTP_LINE_LENGTH_LIMIT=1` to the template and regenerate the config file with `update-exim4.conf`

Comment: Well you can disable it. I leave my Exim alone because why would I want to receive email from people who can't be bothered to follow standards... but that's me.